# Building a recommender system using Surprise

Tags: python, recommendation-engine

So I am using this python library called [Surprise](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

The problem that I am running to is that I can't get my algorithm to predict correctly as I run into this error.
[image: prints this saying the item doesnt exist.]

However the item does exist as you can see in my dataframe:
[image: Dataframe]

I followed the documentation correctly loading in the data using:

```
 # The columns must correspond to user id, item id and ratings (in that order). 
 train_data = Dataset.load_from_df(games_data[['userid', 'name', 'metascore']], reader)
```

The documentation suggested that I look at this https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/FAQ.html#raw-inner-note but I was confused by it.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Is your raw_id numeric enclosed in a string or alphanumeric?

Comment: my raw_id is a string.